# Сделать всё одним запросом.

Tags: php, оптимизация, запрос-в-запросе, mysql

PHP код:

```
// открываем таблицу с пользователями
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $user_id = $data['uid']; // id пользователя

 // открываем материалы пользователя
 $query_ents = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ents` WHERE `uid` = '$user_id'");
 while($data_ents = mysql_fetch_array($query_ents)) {
  echo ...; // шаблон материалов
 }
}
```

Вообщем, есть таблица **users** и **ents**. У каждого пользователя будет выводиться весь список его материалов.

Насколько я знаю, мой код - быдлокод + запрос в цикле. Можно же как-то одним запросом всё сделать?

Помогите с этим, пожалуйста...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM users, ents
Where ents.uid=users.uid
```

Comment: @Ale_x, как добавить ещё например таблицу logs?

Comment: тогда структуры таблиц и поля их связывающие напишите